# ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 using Helper function on laravel excel export file

Tags: excel, laravel

> ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 using Helper function on laravel excel export file.

Show value when I dd(Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)[0]->challan_no). But When I try to show though out in excel it show error.

```
if (count(Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)) > 1)
                            {
                                $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] =Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)[$g]->challan_no;
                            }else{
                               
                                $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] = Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)[0]->challan_no;
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I simply add '@' before Helper function.

```
if (count(Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)) > 1)
                            {
                                $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] = @Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)[$g]->challan_no;
                            }else{
                               
                                $excel_dynamic_data_values[$index][] = @Helper::getChallanData($purchaseLedger->bill_id)[0]->challan_no;

                        }
```